# How to design progress bar with data static like this

Tags: android-studio

I am going to design progress bar with data static like below. But i cant find how to make it. The progress bar with data static will be like this

[image]

Comment: Negative because you are saying static data but your image is about progress bar. Need proper explanation what you want to ask.

Comment: @Abhishek how to make progress bar like that?

Comment: Look at https://android-dev-examples.blogspot.in/2014/09/android-custom-horizontal-progressbar.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to write special drawable style to achieve like this design.

**progess_bar_drawable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>

            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:endColor="@color/seek_bar_default" <!-- your_primary_color -->
                android:startColor="@color/seek_bar_default" /> <!-- your_primary_color -->
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <corners android:radius="3dp" />

                <gradient
                    android:angle="90"
                    android:endColor="@color/completed_green" <!-- your_secodnary_color -->
                    android:startColor="@color/completed_green" /> <!-- your_secondary_color -->
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Here Primary colour is the unfilled colour and Secondary colour is filled color

**In your layout file :**

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar_completed"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="100"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/video_progress_bar"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<ProgressBar
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="20"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/video_progress_bar"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<ProgressBar
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="50"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/video_progress_bar"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<ProgressBar
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="70"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/video_progress_bar"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

[image: Progress bar design]